# Android inflate XML selector to be used in StateListDrawable

Tags: android, android-xml, android-selector

Is it possible to inflate a selector created in XML to be used by `StateListDrawable` programmatically?

I found that `StateListDrawable` has an `inflate` method, but I don't find usage examples.

That would be nice to avoid made this:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] { }, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
imageView.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Does somebody know if it is possible and provide an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible of course. You'll find more information to every other drawable available with [the documentation for State list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList). I hope this answer comes in handy for anyone even six years later.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```